# Wordpress blog in subfolder of ruby main site using Apache Alias not working

Tags: ruby-on-rails, wordpress, apache, .htaccess

Our site has 2 sections, the main site that's ruby and a blog that's Wordpress.  The ruby site is fine but I'm having an issue with the blog in a subfolder.  All the pages work but the homepage and the admin isn't working without initially putting /index.php at the end.  I'm pretty sure the issue/fix is in the Apache conf file and/or .htaccess.  Here they are.

**Apache conf file**

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
    ServerName site.com
    DocumentRoot /var/www/site/code/public

    PassengerRuby /home/site/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.9@site/wrappers/ruby
    RailsEnv production
    RackEnv production

    ErrorLog /var/www/site/code/log/error.log
    CustomLog /var/www/site/code/log/requests.log combined

    Alias /blog/ "/var/www/blog/wordpress"

    <Directory "/var/www/blog/wordpress">
          DirectoryIndex index.php
          AllowOverride All
          Options Indexes FollowSymLinks MultiViews
    </Directory>
</VirtualHost>
```

and the **.htaccess** is pretty much the standard one

```
# BEGIN WordPress
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /blog/
RewriteRule ^index\.php$ - [L]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule . /blog/index.php [L]
</IfModule>

# END WordPress
```

If I go to site.com/blog it shows me the Ruby's site 404 page.

Any help much appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

I've just found the solution and I'm posting it here just incase it can help someone else.  After the Alias line in httpd.conf I added the following

```
<Location /blog>
    PassengerEnabled off
</Location>
```

A simple change but hard to find!!